# Google Maps iOS API Tiles Not Loaded When Zooming Out Or Scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm having a strange issue that seems to have only recently crept up. My code (viewDidLoad):

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(myLocation!.latitude, longitude: myLocation!.longitude, zoom: 20)
let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds, camera: camera)
mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite
self.mainMapView.addSubview(mapView)
```

I'm not setting my map by `self.view = mapView` because I'm using an overlay view on top of the map for added controls (doesn't seem to effect the problem either way).

When I zoom out or scroll beyond what I assume is the tiles loaded for the camera position, the view is black and the new tiles never load. Is there a delegate I'm missing? [image: Zoomed out and panned from initial camera position]

Comment: Uh oh. Looks like it's a Google problem. Using their demo app, with Satellite MapType exhibits the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a bug on Google's end.

Here is the issue and resolution link
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9384